# Don't know how to use if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do not know how to use the if statement to compare the data to enter the user with the database. I want to achieve that the user can enter the bar code of a product and the application looks if that code is stored. If it is found, you can send the following form, otherwise they send a warning message to the user. This is form where you should go and its respective controller.

Form which must be used if statement:

```
<%= @medicinas.each do |p| %> 
INGRESE EL CÓDIGO DE BARRA DEL PRODUCTO QUE DESEA AGREGAR:

<% if codigo == @medicinas.codigo %>
INGRESE OTRO CÓDIGO DE BARRAS, EL QUE ESTA UTILIZANDO YA SE ENCUENTRA ALMACENADO

<% else %> AGREGAR MEDICAMENTO end
```

Controller form:

```
def buscarcrear
  @medicinas = Medicamentos.all
end
```

now i have this error: undefined local variable or method `codigo' for #<#:0x2e96770>
Extracted source (around line #33):

30:                 
31:                 
32:                 <% @medicinas.each do |p| %> 
33:                 <% if codigo == @p.codigobarras %>

what can i do?

Comment: Care to translate the identifiers in your code to english?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're doing the `if`/`else` statement mostly right. Make sure the `end` statement is an ERB style `<% end %>` as well, though.

```
<% if codigo == @medicinas.codigo %>
  INGRESE OTRO CÓDIGO DE BARRAS, EL QUE ESTA UTILIZANDO YA SE ENCUENTRA ALMACENADO
<% else %>
  AGREGAR MEDICAMENTO
<% end %>
```

You may have a problem with `@medicinas.codigo` unless, for some reason, that collection responds to `codigo`, which I doubt? So maybe you meant to call `if codigo == p.codigo` instead? That is, ask the specific medicine instance for its `codigo`.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus, you don't need to add this on the view or the controller, add it as a validation on your model like this:

```
class Medicina < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_uniqueness_of :codigo
end
```

Then on your controller, check to see item was saved or not:

```
if @medicina@.save
  redirect_to .....
else

end
```

Check this part of the guide on how to properly display the errors on the view:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors